# JavaWebstart JNLP windows on windows task bar?

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

I developed JNLP GUI using jgoodies.

The GUI appears when I connect to the website.

But the GUI window is not on the windows task bar(in the bottom side).

The code is like below.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

var attributes = { id:'TSToolkitReal',code:'tradesign.pkitoolkit.applet.MainApplet', width:100, height:100} ;
var parameters = {jnlp_href: '../download/_local_pkitoolkit.jnlp',
                 separate_jvm:true, classloader_cache:false} ;
     deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
```

Comment: 1) What is your question?  2) The code for the JGoodies site is launching an applet.  Applets do not typically get a task-bar icon.

Comment: If the browser is clicked, the applet goes behind. The browser needs to be resized or minimized to get the applet in front which is inconvenient. I want to put the icon on task bar, so user can click it to get the applet in front.

Comment: *"If the browser is clicked, the applet goes behind."*  Really?  Show me the URL where this happens.